# What's the proper technique for using psyllium as a thickening agent?

Tags: sauce, thickening, gravy

I've tried using psyllium husks as a thickening agent, but the result usually ends up containing slimy lumps.

Is there a special technique to produce uniform thickening?

And ideally, how can it be done while using a pressure cooker?

(*Note that suggesting using some other product instead is not an acceptable answer.*)

Comment: What do you mean by "some other product"? There are refined thickeners based on psillium husk, but if you are restricted to using the ground husk itself, then you have already done what can be done. A plant husk is never soluble, per default.

Comment: @rumtscho, by "other product" I meant don't answer with "use cornstarch instead".

Comment: @rumtscho, the husk absorbs water and gels, which thickens the liquid it's in. The problem is that unless it is continuously stirred during the cooking, it often forms noticeable clumps that aren't smoothly mixed in with the rest.

Comment: @RayButterworth Well, your last comment already answered your question - continuous stirring. That happens with any other thickening agent (cornstarch, wheat flour, tapioca flour, xantham gum, CMC...). If you don't stir it, it will form lumps.

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza, that doesn't help with a pressure cooker.

Comment: @RayButterworth what are you trying to make with psyllium and a pressure cooker? Because you have to either stir in and incorporate your psyllium before cooking or after cooking (e.g. thickening the liquid from an pressure cooker roast)